# listdir a directory and find if a file name that endswith ".mp4""

Tags: python

Original question:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4]

print [True for i in a if i == 4]
```

result:

```
[True, True]
```

How do I code to break at first number 4?

Following comments, edited to:

I exactly want to listdir a directory with so many files. And find if a file endswith ".mp4".

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Currently you are just constructing a list of the elements that _match_ your condition, i.e. the two `4`s in your list.

Comment: I exactly want to listdir a directory with so many files. And find if a file endswith ".mp4".

Comment: @Levi:  that's a different question altogether!  Use `glob.glob('name/*.mp4')`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your comment:
"*I exactly want to listdir a directory with so many files. And find if a file endswith ".mp4"*"

That is quite a bit different to the original question you posted.  There are several ways to do this:

```
import glob
import os.path

dir = '.'
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir, '*.mp4'))
print files
```

The advantage of `glob` is that you only capture the filenames you actually need, saving memory.

But since you explicitly ask for `listdir()`:

```
import os
dir = '.'
allfiles = os.listdir(dir)
files = [ fname for fname in allfiles if fname.endswith('.mp4')]
print files
```

Comment: /@cdarke  Can you please edit the question or mark as duplicate.

Comment: @Merlin:  question edited